# Why are my sessions getting blown away upon app redeployment in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm running a standard build of Tomcat, version 7.0.54. Every time I redeploy my app, all sessions are cleared; although, interestingly, restarting Tomcat *does not* lead to sessions being cleared.

My app is written in Scala and based on the [Scalatra framework](http://scalatra.org/), though I'm fairly certain that's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Another standard solution for this issue is storing the session in a database, see also [clustering](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-clustering).

Comment: Take a look at Spring Session. It doesn't require Spring (though it has nice integrations with it) and externalizes your session store to eliminate container whims.

Comment: Thank. Spring Session appears to be worth a closer look... I'll report back when I get a chance to play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (and absurdly) Tomcat blows away the contents of the directory where the default persisted-sessions file lives upon redeployment. To address the issue, specify a custom location for this file, outside of Tomcat's usual playground.

A line similar to the following, within Tomcat's `context.xml` file should do the trick:

```
<Manager pathname="/some/path/persisted-sessions.ser" />
```

(Thanks to [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/131yakenx0/session-persistence-across-application-redeploy) for pointing out the solution. I spent a lot of time futzing with the issue, so wanted to make the solution more discover-able by adding it here to StackOverflow.)

---

**Disclaimer**: SlipperySeal's comment should be noted: "A new deployment could introduce incompatibilities between the session and the app."

In other words, you have to be a little careful with this, and should you make any changes to what/how/where your application is storing things in the session, you'll have to manually remove the persisted sessions file upon deployment of the updated app.

Answer (score 1):

The session information of a deployment artefact are tightly coupled.

A new deployment could introduce incompatibilities between the session and the app. Serialized objects could be incompatible and the "meaning" of values in the session may also change with a new version of code.

Restarting the server without redeploying the application can't cause this problem as the sessions and deployment will stay in sync.

If the sessions were not cleared your users might see unexpected errors, or worse, the application may behave incorrectly, allowing them higher permissions or causing other damage.

As mentioned by Chris, you can store the sessions out of Tomcats deletion reach, but you might want to consider what I have said about breaking changes. If you know the model has changed in such a way, perhaps delete the sessions yourself. If not, obviously leave them be.